# Portrait layout doesnt work when activity starts in landscape

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, landscape-portrait

This is a scaled down version of the actual problem. To recreate the difficulty I am facing.

I have taken the example from the official website `developer.android.com` to cite my problem.
[Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

`MainActivity` has 2 layouts. One is for the default(portrait in small screen devices) layout in the `layout` folder. The other layout for both large-screen and landscape mode, kept in `layout-large` and `layout-land` folder.

Default layout for `activity_main.xml` contains only one `FrameLayout` (`R.id.fragment_container`) in which I add and replace 2 fragments that I create, dynamically.

The other layout is same for both the `layout-land` and `layout-large` folders. It has 2 static fragments [`R.id.headlines_fragment` - to display a list of headlines] and [`R.id.article_fragment` - to display the details when headlines are selected]. Horizontally placed. One on the left to show the lists and the one on the right to show details.

This is the code for `MainActivity.java` which controls all the fragments :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnHeadLineSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_article);          

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
        if(articleFrag != null && articleFrag.isVisible()) {
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        } else {

            articleFrag = new ArticleFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, articleFrag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }       
}
```

As soon as the activity is started, I check if `fragment_container` that is the `FrameLayout` is present or not. If it is not present, then the layout with the 2 fragments has been loaded. Hence no need to add the fragments dynamicaly as they are already present.

Otherwise, I check if the `savedInstanceState` is null or not. If null, then I create a new `HeadlinesFragment` and add it to the frame. If it is not null, then it means that the activity has already been created previously, and hence the `HeadlinesFragment` must have been added already. No need to add it again. So, `return`.

And `onArticleSelected()` method replaces the existing fragment in the frame with the `ArticleFragment`, or if in the other layout, it simply updates the fragment as it is already present. It is called from the `HeadlinesFragment` when an item is selected.

Now, this all works perfectly well if we enter the activity in portrait mode and then change the orientation. No problem. Flawless.

But if we enter the activity in the `landscape` mode, as soon as I change the orientation to the portrait mode, a blank screen is shown.

The reason being, the `onCreate()` is called, and the `savedInstanceState` returns as not `null`. Hence, the `HeadlinesFragment` is not created and added to the frame.

And yes, if I remove that check, then the app works fine, but that will mean that a new `HeadlinesFragment` is created and added to the frame each time and gets stacked on top of eachother. Which is not at all desirable.

I cannot implement this by just finding out the `orientation` and applying the appropriate layout. Because, in large-screen devices, even if it is in portrait mode, it is supposed to show both the fragments at once.

I have tried many convoluted logic. But nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

**Entering activity in portrait mode**

**1>** List Items are shown.

**2>** Clicking items replaces the fragment with the ArticleFragment (details).

**3>** Changing the orientation, shows both side by side. Everything works.

[image: HeadlinesFragment is shown.] ---> [image: ArticleFragment is shown on clicking a list item]

[image: Both shown in the landscape mode]

**Entering activity in landscape mode**

**1>** Both the list and details are shown. Everything works.

**2>** But as soon as the orientation changes, you get the blank screen. As Headlines fragment is not created and added.

[image: Entering Activity in landscape mode] --> [image: HeadlinesFragment not shown. Nothing loads. Blank Screen.]

It would be really helpful if someone could guide me as to how I can solve this problem. And as the actual project is huge, and this logic has already been implemented, a drastic change in logic is not an option anymore as that will mean re writting thousands of lines of code. Thank you. :)

Comment: You can use the .replace mtehod instead of the .add to avoid stacking fragments on top of each other. This will not solve the fact that a new fragment is created every time though

Comment: Ofcourse I have thought of that but what about the first time the activity is created? there is nothing in the frame to replace. I did try it. It throws an exception. So, not an option. :(

Comment: Does it really throw an exception? I rarely use the add method because it's more convenient and I haven't had that problem. What exception do you get?

Comment: You have to add something to the framelayout the first time, then only you can replace it from the next time on. But this does give me an idea. what if I put in a random fragment statically in the xml file itself. Then I can call replace on it everytime. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I got the problem. The problem is we are using `Fragments` in xml layouts in large devices.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So android is trying to catch the Fragments in `savedInstanceState` in MainActivity. When screen rotates, system tries to restore the above Fragments even though different layout loads in potrait mode. And so system considers that the `article_fragment` is also available on the right side and it tries to update it on click on the **Headline**.

**So, What's the solution ?**

I have changed a little code in MainActivity and nothing else :-)

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            /*if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }*/

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

So what I have done just I told the system that I don't want any thing restored by using `super.onCreate(null);` so its restoring nothing now.

**About the blank screen you are getting**

Whenever you start activity in landscape mode. It loads large display by default. Without entering into **if satement**. Because it can't get `fragment_container` in landscape mode. And then you rotate screen to load **portrait layout** and system gets `savedInstanceState != null` and it returns without loading `HeadlinesFragment`. So you get bank screen.

So I have commented If statement as you can notice.

```
/*if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    return;
  }*/
```

**So now It load everything correctly.
No issue**

Comment: Seems like a possible solution. I will test it today. If it works, then I'll come back and accept this answer. Anyway, thank you for your time and effort. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: Don't worry. I have already tested this. Anyway I am developer not a good tester...

Answer (score 0):

Download the code sample from this Developer site and modify it according to your needs.

[Build Dynamic UI with fragments](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Its super and reliable code.

Comment: If you will notice, this is exactly my code. This is the exact problem I copied here. It works well for large screen and small screen devices. Yet fails in orientation change.

Comment: oh ! Let me test the code. I will reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are reasons why the `Fragment` was rendered correctly in `Portrait -> Landscape` and not in the reverse but one thing is very clear about the `Activity` lifecycle

> Called when the activity is starting. This is where most
>   initialization should go: calling `setContentView(int)` to inflate the
>   activity's UI, using `findViewById(int)` to programmatically interact
>   with widgets in the UI, calling `managedQuery(android.net.Uri,
>   String[], String, String[], String)` to retrieve cursors for data
>   being displayed, etc.

Note the part that says **This is where most initialization should go**. By exiting after checking that `savedInstanceState` is null, you're leaving it up to the `super` class to restore your `Fragment` which is not a good idea considering the previous view was destroyed.

My advice, inspect the content of `savedInstanceState` instead of just checking if it is null. Ensure that it contains enough data to restore your previous state, if not **initialize** your Fragment.

The best practices with Fragments involve implementing all necessary methods to monitor the state.

Comment: That is not a problem, because, once I enter portrait mode, changing orientation multiple times doesnot affect the fragments. savedInstanceState does have the appropriate information. The problem occurs on the creation of the activity from the landscape mode. THe bundle is not null, yet there is no information about the fragment. Because it hasnot been created. I know that. I know the exact problem. Yes, the savedInstanceState in that case does not have the fragment. I know that. but I cant find out a way to fix it without hampering the rest of the code. I have tried a lot. :(

Comment: @SamratDutta if possible, can I access the complete source so I can run it and inspect?